# Sass - Web Compiler replaces Url as relatives urls

Tags: css, sass, web-compiler

I have a problem with Web Compiler with VS2015 Update 1 and Sass.

In my Scss file, i declared some images as background.

Example :

```
.example {
     background-image: url(images/ex.jpg);
}
```

In the file compilerconfig.json, the outPutFile is not in the same directory.
In the file compilerconfig.json.defaults, i set relativeUrls as false in sass section.
When i compile, url becomes relative like :

```
.example {
         background-image: url(../../../../../images/ex.jpg);
    }
```

I have the same problem with imported file.

Is there any way to resolve this ?

Comment: A simple search said that in the SASS options you can set a document root with `:template_location`

Comment: I am using a VS extension WebCompiler, not a ruby watcher with the folders sass, stylesheets...
I edit my scss file, i save and the VS extension generates the css and min.css files.
So, where can i set the option ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found how to disable relative urls :
the option is not to set in the file compilerconfig.json.defaults but in compilerconfig.json :

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/ui/skins/test.css",
    "inputFile": "Web/Stylesheets/test.scss",
    "minify": {
      "termSemicolons": true
    },
    "options": {
      "relativeUrls": false,
      "lineFeed": "crlf"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I've didn't catch the part that you where using a web compiler, but thanks for adding a solution.